# I have fortnightly(fourteen)dates,i want op as 14 dates and amount based on deal date and maturity date

Tags: plsql

My question is:
i have two tables(A and B) as below

A

```
 deal_no deal_date deal_amnt
    501 `20180525` `10`
    502 `20180526` `20`
    601 `20180528` `30`
    602 `20180529` `40`
```

B

```
 deal_type  maturity_date
    501 `20180525`
    502 `20180527`
    601 `20180530`
    602 `20180530`
```

For the same deal_no(deal_type),if deal_date from A = maturity_date from B then deal_amnt for maturity_date should be same 
eg(for 501--> if(20180525=20180525) then amnt=10)

For the same deal_no(deal_type),if deal_date from A < maturity_date from B then deal_amnt for maturity_date should be same,and it same amount should be upadted under deal_date
eg(for 502--> if(20180526 < 20180527) then amount for 20180527=20 and for 20180526 should also =20)

however, if i am having more than one deal_date having same maturity_date then amount for maturity_date should be sum of that two or more deal_dates.
eg(for 601 --> if(20180528 < 20180530) and for 602 --> if(20180529 < 20180530) 
then amount for 20180528=30 and amount for 20180529 should =((previous 30)+(current 40))=70 and amount for 20180530 should be 70 as outstanding)

I have fortnightly(fourteen)dates,i want op as 14 dates and amount based on deal date and maturity date

op should be:

```
date   `deal_amnt`
20180516 0
20180517 0
20180518 0
20180519 0
20180520 0
20180521 0
20180522 0 
20180523 0
20180524 0
20180525 10
20180526 20
20180527 20
20180528 30
20180529 70
20180530 70
```

Need help i am using plsql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution purely SQL no PL needed

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ad050/2)

**Query 1**:

```
with dts(n, dt) as (
  select 1 n
       , date '2018-05-16'
    from dual
  union all
  select n+1
       , date '2018-05-16' + n
    from dts where n < 15
)
select dt
     , sum(deal_amnt)
  from a
  join b
    on a.deal_no = b.deal_type
 right join dts
    on dts.dt between a.deal_date and b.maturity_date
 group by dt
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ad050/2/0)**:

```
|                   DT | SUM(DEAL_AMNT) |
|----------------------|----------------|
| 2018-05-16T00:00:00Z |         (null) |
| 2018-05-17T00:00:00Z |         (null) |
| 2018-05-18T00:00:00Z |         (null) |
| 2018-05-19T00:00:00Z |         (null) |
| 2018-05-20T00:00:00Z |         (null) |
| 2018-05-21T00:00:00Z |         (null) |
| 2018-05-22T00:00:00Z |         (null) |
| 2018-05-23T00:00:00Z |         (null) |
| 2018-05-24T00:00:00Z |         (null) |
| 2018-05-25T00:00:00Z |             10 |
| 2018-05-26T00:00:00Z |             20 |
| 2018-05-27T00:00:00Z |             20 |
| 2018-05-28T00:00:00Z |             30 |
| 2018-05-29T00:00:00Z |             70 |
| 2018-05-30T00:00:00Z |             70 |
```